# How do I make conditions in printf statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, conditional-statements

I have homework where I have to create a C program which sorts 5 numbers from smallest to largest. I know how to easily program this using functions and `if` statements (using `>=` and `<=`).

However, the catch is I am only allowed to use `printf` and `scanf`, so I have to calculate all the `>=` and `<=` inside the `printf`. And I'm not allowed to use the ternary operator.

I've been trying to a long time. So I tried to sort just 3 numbers, I still can't even get past sorting the smallest number. It just keeps printing `1`.

```
// This printf is just trying to figure out the smallest number from 3 numbers provided but it keeps printing 1.
printf("The ascending order of the numbers are: %d ",
    (
     (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) || // Checking if num1 is the smallest
     (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3) || // Checking if num2 is the smallest
     (num3 <= num2 && num3 <= num1)    // Checking if num3 is the smallest
    ));
```

One possible solution I have come up with is adding the `((num1 + num2 + num3) -1)` because if one of the statements is true (for example if `num2` is the smallest, it would print `1` because `1` means true). If it is false it prints `0`. So I could technically add the statement which is true then `-1`. So if `num2`'s statement is true, I could do `+ num2 - 1`.

Comment: It prints 1 because the expression is true. Are you allowed to use the ternary operator `a ? b : c`?

Comment: There are 5! = 120 different possible orderings of 5 numbers. Are you *sure* this is your assignment to hard code the sort?

Comment: @user3386109 I am not allowed to use ternary operators

Comment: @MFisherKDX I don't know but that is what I have to do. This subject is just for beginner coders

Comment: @Katie And no ternary either? Either I am misunderstanding, or you are misunderstanding, or your professor is playing a cruel trick on you.

Comment: @MFisherKDX i thought the same thing too but we are suppose to use && and || and != . The only solution I came up with (which I don't even know how to code it) is when I run this code, if one of the 3 "statements" I wrote is true, it prints 1 and if its false, it prints 0. So my solution was to add up ((num1 + num2 + num3) -1), that way, I would technically get the right answer.

For example if (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) is true, it prints 1. So I could make this print + num1 - 1 and it would show the actual answer

Comment: Oh, so you make a statement that's `true`, and then multiple it by one of the numbers. For example `printf("%d", (x>y) * x + (x<y) * y)`.

Comment: @user3386109 I don't know how to code it though... I've tried everything I know with C...

Comment: @Katie.P Are you allowed to use macros?

Comment: @user3386109 it partially worked (the way you said). However if the person using the program inputs the same numbers, it breaks. For example, if the user inputs 5 5 5 then it breaks. Or if the user inputs 5 5 10

Comment: @d3L no we cant use macros

Comment: @user3386109 Can you explain it to me again? I don't understand? Even if you just show me how to do it with one statement (not all 3 statements to check which is the smallest).

Comment: @Katie Jonathan just updated the answer with an example. When multiplying by `num1` allow equality. When multiplying by `num2` don't allow equality with `num1`, but allow equality with all others. When multiplying by `num3`, don't allow equality with `num1` or `num2`, but do allow equality with all others. And so on...

Comment: the value in this assignment is academic only, I suppose, by making you "think outside the box" (I wouldn't come up with a solution to this in any reasonable amount of time). Practically, this is a dumb, stupid, useless assignment at best, and possibly detrimental. Presumably this is CompSci 101 or something equivalent; how many students interested in coding is a task like this going to scare off? Are the students left going to think it's normal to do this much work in `printf`? After this assignment, **never** write code like this again. These asinine requirements (not allowed to use this,

Comment: this, or this), are only useful IMO when you're implementing your own version of a function call to see how it works. Writing your own `strcat` or `pow` functions, for instance, have value. Writing a bubble sort function has value. Even if you figure out a sorting algorithm that has merit, stuffing it all into a `printf` as some kind of extended expression is confusing, hard to read, and hard for others after you to maintain. You should mention this on the class eval.  /rant

Comment: What @yano says.  Whatever this exercise teaches, it's not C programming.

Comment: I'll add my 2 cents - all such assignments are detrimental to any kind of effective software development. The more complex and 'clever' the code, the more difficult it is to debug and, more often than necessary, ends up being posted here.   Use temp vars to hold intermediate results, one simple expression per line.   Looks 'inefficient'?  Looks like 'beginner code'?  Who cares if you can get your code tested, debugged and working correctly before anyone else:)  100% agree with @yano etc.

Answer (score 7):

#### Pass 1: Minimum of three distinct values

Note that if a condition evaluates to false, the result is `0`; if true, `1`.  So you can use a trick (as long as multiplication and addition aren't verboten too) — for three distinct values as shown in the question:

```
printf("The smallest number is: %d ",
       (num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) +
        num2 * (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3) +
        num3 * (num3 <= num1 && num3 <= num2)));
```

There will be trouble if two values are the same and are also the smaller value.

#### Pass 2: Minimum of five distinct values

If you need to process 5 values, it is (as noted in a comment) more tedious than difficult.

```
printf("The smallest number is: %d ",
       (num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3 && num1 <= num4 && num1 <= num5) +
        num2 * (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3 && num2 <= num4 && num2 <= num5) +
        num3 * (num3 <= num1 && num3 <= num2 && num3 <= num4 && num3 <= num5) +
        num4 * (num4 <= num1 && num4 <= num2 && num4 <= num3 && num4 <= num5) +
        num5 * (num5 <= num1 && num5 <= num2 && num5 <= num3 && num5 <= num4)));
```

This is just for finding the minimum; working it for each of the other cases quickly becomes preposterous.  Indeed, the whole exercise is fairly silly, but it is also fairly typical of some courses.

#### Pass 3: Minimum of three values not necessarily distinct

After a bit of cogitation, I think you can deal with 2 or 3 numbers the same with this (which is basically what [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290953/how-do-i-make-conditions-in-printf-statements/49291191#comment85585542_49290953)).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_smallest(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    printf("The smallest number of (%d, %d, %d) is %d\n",
           num1, num2, num3,
           (num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) +
            num2 * (num2 <  num1 && num2 <= num3) +
            num3 * (num3 <  num1 && num3 <  num2)));
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++)
                print_smallest(i, j, k);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The smallest number of (1, 1, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 1, 2) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 1, 3) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 2, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 2, 2) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 2, 3) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 3, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 3, 2) is 1
The smallest number of (1, 3, 3) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 1, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 1, 2) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 1, 3) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 2, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 2, 2) is 2
The smallest number of (2, 2, 3) is 2
The smallest number of (2, 3, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (2, 3, 2) is 2
The smallest number of (2, 3, 3) is 2
The smallest number of (3, 1, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (3, 1, 2) is 1
The smallest number of (3, 1, 3) is 1
The smallest number of (3, 2, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (3, 2, 2) is 2
The smallest number of (3, 2, 3) is 2
The smallest number of (3, 3, 1) is 1
The smallest number of (3, 3, 2) is 2
The smallest number of (3, 3, 3) is 3
```

#### Pass 4: Sorted order for three values not necessarily distinct

Calculating the maximum instead of the minimum is trivial; simply use `>` in place of `<` throughout.
Calculating the median turns out to be harder.  I suspect there is a better way of doing it than this, but at least this works.  Note the subtracted term — omit that, and the median value is doubled when the three values are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_smallest(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    printf("The sorted order of (%2d, %2d, %2d) is (%2d, %2d, %2d)\n",
           num1, num2, num3,

           (num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) +     /* Min1 */
            num2 * (num2 <  num1 && num2 <= num3) +     /* Min2 */
            num3 * (num3 <  num1 && num3 <  num2)),     /* Min3 */

           (num1 * (num1 >= num2 && num1 <= num3) +     /* Med1 */
            num2 * (num2 >  num1 && num2 <= num3) +     /* Med2 */
            num3 * (num3 >  num1 && num3 <  num2) -     /* Med3 */
            num1 * (num1 == num2 && num1 == num3) +     /* Med4 */
            num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 >= num3) +     /* Med5 */
            num2 * (num2 <  num1 && num2 >= num3) +     /* Med6 */
            num3 * (num3 <  num1 && num3 >  num2)),     /* Med7 */

           (num1 * (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) +     /* Max1 */
            num2 * (num2 >  num1 && num2 >= num3) +     /* Max2 */
            num3 * (num3 >  num1 && num3 >  num2))      /* Max3 */
          );
}

int main(void)
{
    int lo = -7;        // +1, -2
    int hi = +6;        // +4, +4
    int jp = +6;        // +1, +2
    for (int i = lo; i < hi; i += jp)
    {
        for (int j = lo; j < hi; j += jp)
        {
            for (int k = lo; k < hi; k += jp)
                print_smallest(i, j, k);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The sorted order of (-7, -7, -7) is (-7, -7, -7)
The sorted order of (-7, -7, -1) is (-7, -7, -1)
The sorted order of (-7, -7,  5) is (-7, -7,  5)
The sorted order of (-7, -1, -7) is (-7, -7, -1)
The sorted order of (-7, -1, -1) is (-7, -1, -1)
The sorted order of (-7, -1,  5) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-7,  5, -7) is (-7, -7,  5)
The sorted order of (-7,  5, -1) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-7,  5,  5) is (-7,  5,  5)
The sorted order of (-1, -7, -7) is (-7, -7, -1)
The sorted order of (-1, -7, -1) is (-7, -1, -1)
The sorted order of (-1, -7,  5) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-1, -1, -7) is (-7, -1, -1)
The sorted order of (-1, -1, -1) is (-1, -1, -1)
The sorted order of (-1, -1,  5) is (-1, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-1,  5, -7) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-1,  5, -1) is (-1, -1,  5)
The sorted order of (-1,  5,  5) is (-1,  5,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -7, -7) is (-7, -7,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -7, -1) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -7,  5) is (-7,  5,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -1, -7) is (-7, -1,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -1, -1) is (-1, -1,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5, -1,  5) is (-1,  5,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5,  5, -7) is (-7,  5,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5,  5, -1) is (-1,  5,  5)
The sorted order of ( 5,  5,  5) is ( 5,  5,  5)
```

#### Pass 5: Sorted order for three values, no loops or function

As before, the code in Pass 4 does a thorough test of all combinations of three numbers in their relative positions.  If you're required to read three numbers and then sort them (and you're not allowed to use loops or functions other than `main()`, `scanf()`, `printf()`, so be it — you can transplant the `printf()` statement into your `main()` immediately after you've read three values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;

    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to read 3 integers\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("The sorted order of (%2d, %2d, %2d) is (%2d, %2d, %2d)\n",
           num1, num2, num3,

           (num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) +     /* Min1 */
            num2 * (num2 <  num1 && num2 <= num3) +     /* Min2 */
            num3 * (num3 <  num1 && num3 <  num2)),     /* Min3 */

           (num1 * (num1 >= num2 && num1 <= num3) +     /* Med1 */
            num2 * (num2 >  num1 && num2 <= num3) +     /* Med2 */
            num3 * (num3 >  num1 && num3 <  num2) -     /* Med3 */
            num1 * (num1 == num2 && num1 == num3) +     /* Med4 */
            num1 * (num1 <= num2 && num1 >= num3) +     /* Med5 */
            num2 * (num2 <  num1 && num2 >= num3) +     /* Med6 */
            num3 * (num3 <  num1 && num3 >  num2)),     /* Med7 */

           (num1 * (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) +     /* Max1 */
            num2 * (num2 >  num1 && num2 >= num3) +     /* Max2 */
            num3 * (num3 >  num1 && num3 >  num2))      /* Max3 */
          );

    return 0;
}
```

Testing with a random number generator (program name `sort3-53`) yields:

```
$ for i in $(range 0 9); do random -n 3 10 99 | sort3-53; done
The sorted order of (66, 62, 70) is (62, 66, 70)
The sorted order of (43, 99, 23) is (23, 43, 99)
The sorted order of (20, 46, 66) is (20, 46, 66)
The sorted order of (87, 82, 19) is (19, 82, 87)
The sorted order of (63, 29, 62) is (29, 62, 63)
The sorted order of (40, 66, 15) is (15, 40, 66)
The sorted order of (17, 13, 58) is (13, 17, 58)
The sorted order of (84, 50, 11) is (11, 50, 84)
The sorted order of (60, 86, 54) is (54, 60, 86)
The sorted order of (37, 33, 96) is (33, 37, 96)
$
```

You can probably use `seq` where I use `range`.  I'm not sure there's a standard PRNG program analogous to the `random` I use (and wrote).  The invocation shown generates 3 random numbers between 10 and 99 inclusive.

#### How it should be done?

The whole process here is preposterous — but that's because of the conditions placed on the techniques that can be used.  If you need to sort three or more numbers, put them in an array, sort the array, and print the array.  Failing that, you should swap the values to find the sorted order; it would dramatically reduce the number of comparisons needed, and there'd be no multiplications.

Comment: Yeah, now I'd like to see the code that prints the second largest of five numbers :)

Comment: @user3386109: It would be more tedious than difficult.  The exercise is ridiculous — but that's not as unusual as you'd like to think.

Comment: Agreed, if this is indeed the expected answer, then the exercise is ridiculous.

Comment: The only way I'd attempt this exercise is by writing code to generate the code. I fail to understand how this is a beginner question or even the point of this exercise.

Comment: This solution partially worked. However if the user inputs the same number for example 5 5 5 or 5 5 10 the multiplication fails

Comment: @MFisherKDX: I didn't actually generate the 5-number code by program, but I probably would if it was necessary to go further.  But it is an exercise; even for 5, the right way is to use an array and sort it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could you explain how I would fix it just with 3 numbers? I don't understand how to fix it. If I understand, I can fix it myself. This exercise is stupid and there are million better ways then doing it this way, but I have to do it this way.

Comment: You could also use &, |, ~ and -1 to replace * and +.  I think this works: `(num1 & ~((num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3)-1)) | (num2 & .... )`

Comment: @Katie.P: see the update — it can be done, but it isn't wholly trivial.  There is a pattern in the use of `<` and `<=`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Not allowed to use functions... Only printf and scanf :L But I will try using the <= and <, though I don't fully get it

Comment: @Katie.P: You can move the printf into `main()` and rename the loop variables; but you're already using 3 functions (`main()`, `printf()`, `scanf()`) anyway.  I'm not bound by all the constraints you're bound by.  It is trivial to get back within the constraints that you're under.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am a new programmer, basically we aren't allowed to use the static void thing (because we haven't learnt that). We are only allowed to put this in the main function. Not allowed to use the "for" or anything but printf and scanf. Not even int for anything but the scanf

Comment: @Katie.P: You had `num1` — which is presumably declared `int num1;` (or perhaps `short` or `char`).  I'm doing an exhaustive test — I'm blowed if I'm typing that many test cases by hand.  You can extract the `printf()` statement from the function I wrote and place in your `main()` function (see — you are writing a function!) where you had your non-working function call.  This is the point at which you start learning programming.  You've been shown the trick (and it is just a trick; it isn't a good general technique — I've not used it before) and now need to adapt it to your case.

Comment: What I'm still puzzling over is: *What in the world was the expected answer??* Jonathan Leffler is one of the most experienced C programmers on SO, and he could only barely begin to solve this problem.  There's no way a student in an ordinary C programming class could have.  So either something got lost in translation, or the instructor who set this assignment is a truly malicious sadist.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that can be easily adapted for any number of values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n[5], o[5], s[5];

    while (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &n[0], &n[1], &n[2], &n[3], &n[4]) == 5) {
        o[0] = (n[0] >  n[1]) + (n[0] >  n[2]) + (n[0] >  n[3]) + (n[0] >  n[4]);
        o[1] = (n[1] >= n[0]) + (n[1] >  n[2]) + (n[1] >  n[3]) + (n[1] >  n[4]);
        o[2] = (n[2] >= n[0]) + (n[2] >= n[1]) + (n[2] >  n[3]) + (n[2] >  n[4]);
        o[3] = (n[3] >= n[0]) + (n[3] >= n[1]) + (n[3] >= n[2]) + (n[3] >  n[4]);
        o[4] = (n[4] >= n[0]) + (n[4] >= n[1]) + (n[4] >= n[2]) + (n[4] >= n[3]);
        s[o[0]] = n[0];
        s[o[1]] = n[1];
        s[o[2]] = n[2];
        s[o[3]] = n[3];
        s[o[4]] = n[4];
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `while` is only used to repeat the input / sort / output phase. You can get rid of it if no `if` or `while` statement is allowed, but then I do not know how to test for successful `scanf()` conversion, yet undefined behavior can be avoided via initialization:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, s[5];

    n0 = n1 = n2 = n3 = n4 = 0;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &n0, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
    s[(n0 >  n1) + (n0 >  n2) + (n0 >  n3) + (n0 >  n4)] = n0;
    s[(n1 >= n0) + (n1 >  n2) + (n1 >  n3) + (n1 >  n4)] = n1;
    s[(n2 >= n0) + (n2 >= n1) + (n2 >  n3) + (n2 >  n4)] = n2;
    s[(n3 >= n0) + (n3 >= n1) + (n3 >= n2) + (n3 >  n4)] = n3;
    s[(n4 >= n0) + (n4 >= n1) + (n4 >= n2) + (n4 >= n3)] = n4;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use `int` which I presume you do (how else could you store the user input) why not use a precomputed table with the correct sorting?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int map[2][2] = {
    {1, 0},
    {0, 1}
};

int main() {
    int n[2] = {7, 5};

    int tmp  = n[0] >= n[1];

    printf("1.) %d\n", n[map[tmp][0]]);
    printf("2.) %d\n", n[map[tmp][1]]);
}
```

**UPDATE**: This seems to work for three numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int map[2][2][2][3] = {
    {
        {
            {2, 1, 0},
            {1, 2, 0}
        },
        {
            {2, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 0}
        }
    },
    {
        {
            {0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 2}
        },
        {
            {0, 2, 1},
            {0, 1, 2}
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int n[3] = {30, 59, 100};

    int tmp1 = n[0] > n[2];
    int tmp2 = n[0] > n[1];
    int tmp3 = n[1] > n[2];

    printf("1.) %d\n", n[map[tmp1][tmp2][tmp3][0]]);
    printf("2.) %d\n", n[map[tmp1][tmp2][tmp3][1]]);
    printf("3.) %d\n", n[map[tmp1][tmp2][tmp3][2]]);
}
```