# How to write a 3 integer ascending order algorithm in C with just if statements?

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out a way to sort 3 numbers inputted in any given order, into ascending order for a homework assignment. So far I came up with this.

```
if(*p1 > *p3){
            *p3 = *p1;
            }
        if(*p1 > *p2){
            *p2 = *p1;
            }
        if(*p2 > *p3){
            *p3 = *p2;
            }
```

should I add a temp variable in there instead to move it?

Comment: Yes, you lost the value of `*p3` in the second line.

Comment: don't forget about the case where two of the input numbers are identical. I got burned by that on this exact assignment way back when....

Comment: Poke around the code at How do I make conditions in `printf` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290953/how-do-i-make-conditions-in-printf-statements) — which is actually about sorting 3 items without even an `if` statement.  There are various amounts of answer — and some use `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to swap two variables is indeed to add a `temp` variable:

```
void swap(T *a, T *b)
{
    T temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Now, to sort three values into ascending order, a full fledged sorting algorithm would indeed be overkill. You can do this just with a few compares and `swap`s.